# clustering non-stationary data

Tags: clustering, stationarity

I'd like to partition a set of n-dimensional data points into clusters. Each data point is associated with a timestamp. A few challenges for my domain are:

1) The data are non-stationary, such that clusters move over time.

2) Because of this motion, clusters sometimes split or merge.

3) I don't know a priori how many clusters there should be

Can anyone recommend a clustering algorithm suited for this scenario (i.e. that can handle cluster parameters changing over time)? Something that has been implemented in Matlab, R, or python would be especially helpful.

Comment: Interesting.  Are you looking for a separate cluster solution for every point in time?  Also, when you say that clusters move, split, or merge, do you mean you expect *obtained* clusters to do this, or could you be referring to "true" or "benchmark" clusters (i.e. clusters that exist in some absolute sense, which your analysis is trying to discover)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Ideally, temporally distant datapoints could be assigned to the same cluster. The key feature would be that the center and extent of a particular partition would be time-dependent. The clusters exist in some absolute sense, although splitting and merging represent failures to disambiguate two "true" clusters before splitting or after merging.